# How to send react object to rails api with a post fetch request? 406 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, http-status-code-406

I am currently working on a project using react and ruby on rails. My goal right now is to send a post request using fetch to create and store my user in my backend api on submission of my react form. My problem is, the backend isn't receiving my data correctly, resulting in a 406 error. I feel like i've tried everything, i'm going crazy, help.

REACT CODE:

form-

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" required value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} name="name" placeholder="name"/>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" required value={password} onChange={handlePasswordChange} name="password" placeholder="password"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Create Account"/>
            </form>
```

methods -

```
 const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

    const handleNameChange = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    }

    const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {name, password}
    
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                Content_Type: "application/json",
            }
        })
```

RAILS CODE:

users controller-

```
def create
      user = User.create(user_params)
      if user.valid?
        payload = {user_id: user.id}
        token = encode_token(payload)
        render json: { user: user, jwt: token }
      else
        render json: { error: 'failed to create user' }, status: :not_acceptable
      end
    end
  
    private
  
    def user_params
      params.permit(:name, :password)
    end
```

error -
[backend error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eal4N.png)

Comment: Probably because the header name isn't correct, can you try to change it to { "Content-Type" : "application/json" } instead?

Comment: @nasser17 AND just like that you saved me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `user.valid?` returns `false`, so your `else` statement kicks in:

```
render json: { error: 'failed to create user' }, status: :not_acceptable
```

The `status: :not_acceptable` generates the `406` error.

You should probably include the reason why user is not valid, and return a bad request response instead:

```
render json: { error: user.errors.full_messages}, status: :bad_request
```